# JQuery Binding Context

Tags: jquery, binding

I have something like this code:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < interactions.length; i++) {
            action = interactions[i].split(':');

            if (events.indexOf(action[0]) >= 0) {
                $(this).bind(action[0], function (e) {
                    if (action.length == 2) {
                        model[action[1]]();
                    }
                    else if (action.length == 3) {
                        var args = action[2].split('|');
                        model[action[1]].apply(null, args);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The variable "events" is simply a string with event names like 'click,dblclick' etc... The issue is when I get inside the event, the "action" variable is losing context. This appears to be a closure like construct in which "action" should stay in context but it doesn't. In this example I have two interactions as in:

1) click:Save

2) disabled:SomeCustomFunction

So, when I perform a click event, I would expect action[1] to be "Save" but it's actually "disabled". So, it's like whatever it was last set to, thats what I get.

Any ideas how to keep things in context?

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time the event handler runs (when a click or whatever actually happens) `action` will be equal to whatever it was on the last iteration of the `for` loop. If `action` was a local variable in a function called on each iteration *then* you'd get the closure construct you need.

Since you are using jQuery already the easiest change is to use `$.each()` instead of a plain `for` loop, thus putting the processing of each iteration into its own closure with its own `action`:

```
   $.each(interactions, function(i, item) {
        var action = item.split(':');

        if (events.indexOf(action[0]) >= 0) {
            $(this).bind(action[0], function (e) {
                if (action.length == 2) {
                    model[action[1]]();
                }
                else if (action.length == 3) {
                    var args = action[2].split('|');
                    model[action[1]].apply(null, args);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: your right, what a stupid mistake to make! Answer removed since its not helpful to the OP...

Comment: Very nice thought but its still not working. Its still holding on to the last action that was set. I'm still digging :-(

Comment: Whoops, actually, you are absolutely correct. I forgot to put the "var" in front of action. Thank you so much for your helpfult answer.

Comment: Had to make a slight adjustment. Just above the interactions loop I had to declare a new variable as in:

var self = this; then for the bind I used "self" inseatd of "this". Everything is working perfectly now. Awesome help. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about the `this` thing, I should've thought of that. I'm happy you got it working.